# What is the simplest/easiest way to display line of text only when printing a webpage using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a line of text I would like to display only when a webpage is being printed.  Is it possible to only display this line when printing the page or doing a print preview using PHP in some way?

Basically, I want to print a page without the print headers, but would like to include the page's URL within the page's content when it is printed.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I added some additional detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a CSS stylesheet that only applies to Print media.

For example:

```
                                             Notice the media----v
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

In your regular CSS stylesheet, just hide that element:

```
p.print-notice {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And in your print CSS stylesheet, bring it up again:

```
p.print-notice {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

---

*Note: Setting visibility to hidden, only hides the element but does **not** remove it from the document flow. Use the Display property if you want to remove it from flow.*

Answer (score 1):

You might have more luck doing this with CSS and just showing or hiding the element(s) when printing using "@media print". A little more information is here: http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/qt/tipcssatmedia.htm but you can probably find more by doing some searches for CSS media types.